# node.js/socket.io how to separate javascript of the html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file, socket.io

I want to separate Javascript code of the Html.

This is my current index.html :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Test</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <p>Welcome</p>
            <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
            <script>
              var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And I would like this :

index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Test</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <p>Welcome</p>
            <script src="client.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

client.js

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

My server route is set like that : (express + fs)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.write(content);
        res.end();
    });
});
```

I have to send client.js too ? Actually, Javascript Console on index.html says "Cannot GET http::localhost/client.js".

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot.

Nicolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a folder for the static content, then add this to your express configuration:

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

After that, you can remove the `app.get('/')` route

Comment: Thank you, it's working ! I chose mobile-detect to detect what is the device connected. According that I want to display a different page. Before your help I could manage that in "app.get('/')" route but now I have no idea. Do you know how could I do ? Thank you !

Comment: If you want to handle the '/' route from server, you need to rename your index.html to index_desktop.html or index_mobile.html, and then, you can use the get('/') route and render the file that you need validating the client type with: `req.headers`